# How to log more frequently than evaluating with `ray.tune.Trainable`

Tags: ray

I am interested in using the `tune` library for reinforcement learning and I would like to use the in-built tensorboard capability. However, the metric that I am using to tune my hyperparameters is based on a time-consuming evaluation procedure that should be run infrequently.

According to the documentation, it looks like the `_train` method returns a dictionary that is used both for logging and for tuning hyperparameters. Is it possible either to perform logging more frequently within the `_train` method? Alternately, could I return the values that I wish to log from the `_train` method but some of the time omit the expensive-to-compute metric from the dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use your own logging mechanism in the Trainable. You can log to the trial-specific directory (Trainable.logdir). If this conflicts with the built-in Tensorboard logging, you can remove that by setting `tune.run(loggers=None)`.

Another option is to, as you mentioned, some of the time omit the expensive-to-compute metric from the dictionary. If you run into issues with that, you can also return "None" as the value for those metrics that you don't plan to compute in a particular iteration.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Looking for example at https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/1eaa57c98f8870a43e1ea14ec011b6bd4be97c8d/python/ray/tune/schedulers/async_hyperband.py#L100, it seems like the Schedulers expect the chosen metric to be present in the `results` dict and to be a scalar value.

Comment: Ah I see; you want to use that metric for optimization. One option here is to use a dummy value (i.e., the last seen value) and to provide the more frequently calculated values.

Comment: That's a great idea! That's what I'll do.